# Factory pattern - how to avoid switch construction?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I use simple `Factory pattern`, look at screen, please:

[image]

As you can see I use switch operator to choose object and create instance.

But if there are over 100 classes? Problem is came. 
How to avoid switch construction? Using interface?

Comment: `return new $type(new Position());` should work, (but I'm not sure if you want to do that or not.)

Comment: Do you mean use variable  as class name?

Comment: May be to use additionally another pattern or Abstract Factory?

Comment: I mean, it's possible to do so. I don't know if it's a good idea for your pattern.

Comment: There is no switch on your picture)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Your example works! But for support namespaces, you have to prefix class name with particular namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `switch` or `if` statements by using variable with class name together with `new` keyword the only thing you have to care about is `namespace`! Your code must look like this:

```
$className = "YourNamespace\\SomeFactory\\SomeImplementation\\" . $type;
return new $className(new Position());
```

Also, you can check if class exists:

```
if (class_exists($className) === false) {
    throw new Exception("Class $className not found.");
}
```

and only after that create you new instance.